# AngularJs how to get jwt token from $localStorage with angular-jwt

Tags: angularjs, jwt

I want to config a jwtInterceptor. I found angular-jwt but I don't know how to get the token I saved into $localStorage.

I already created a service that gets the token from $localStorage but I can't inject a Service into a Config, neither can I inject $localStorage into a Config.

Here's the code angular-jwt provided:

```
angular
  .module('app', ['angular-jwt'])
  .config(function Config($httpProvider, jwtOptionsProvider) {
    // Please note we're annotating the function so that the $injector works when the file is minified
    jwtOptionsProvider.config({
      tokenGetter: ['myService', function(myService) {
        myService.doSomething();
        return localStorage.getItem('id_token');
      }]
    });

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('jwtInterceptor');
  })
```

Here's the service I use to save the token into $localStorage:

```
$http.post('/users/api/auth', { email: email, password: password })
                    .then(function (response) {
                        if (response.data.token) {
                            $localStorage.currentUser = { email: email, token: response.data.token, role: response.data.user.role }
                            $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + response.data.token;                                                  
                    });
```

I don't quite understand the myService function, I tried to use it, but I can't call it and run it. How can I get my token and use it on jwtInterceptor config?

Comment: Sounds like you have a typo where you set the value to local storage. Try replacing `$localStorage.currentUser = ...` with `localStorage.setItem(...)`

Comment: You can't inject services directly into config blocks. Try injecting `myServiceProvider` instead, and then do `myServiceProvider.$get().doSomething();`

Comment: I managed to get the token in the tokenGetter changing how I saved it to localStorage. But when I call the http request to register, it still works even the token being null, since the token is only created once logged in.

I know the register request should be public and ignored by the interceptor, but I wanted to test it without being ignored. But even without the argument to ignore the interceptor, the http still works and it's not blocked. Any clues?